# PHP Неверно отрабатывает пользовательская функция

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
$_POST['crm_token'] = '4ab822cb-ecd3-4138-aceb-51c2ac13db7e';
$_POST['cmd'] = 'contact';
$_POST['phone'] = 'phone';
$_POST['callid'] = 'callid';

function check($required, $array)
{
    foreach ($required as $key) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $array))
            return false;
    }
}

$required = array('phone', 'crm_token', 'callid');

if (!$this->check($required, $_POST)) {
    return http_response_code(400);
}
```

В итоге возвращает 400. Почему? Ведь не должно.

Comment: А вы не забыли вернуть true, если все хорошо?

Comment: А он по умолчанию же возвращается, или нет?

Comment: Ставил, но результат был тем же.

Comment: в документации написано If the return is omitted the value NULL will be returned - если return опущен, то вернёт null. А это расценивается как false. Покажите как вы добавляли return в вопросе.

Comment: в конце метода же надо `function check($required, $array)
{
    foreach ($required as $key) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $array))
            return false;
    }
 
 return true;
}`

Comment: Ок, спасибо за комментарии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас функция check должна вернуть true хотя бы в конце!
Вот [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bcffd1503bd60e5650f207aaf0577bac7f0dec3f) и все ок

```
    $arr['crm_token'] = '4ab822cb-ecd3-4138-aceb-51c2ac13db7e';
    $arr['cmd'] = 'contact';
    $arr['phone'] = 'phone';
    $arr['callid'] = 'callid';

    function check($required, $array)
    {
        foreach ($required as $key) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $array))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

$required = array('phone', 'crm_token', 'callid');

if (!check($required, $arr)) {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: Тебе же написали, у тебя и там в функции check нет return true

Comment: А, все, не сохранилось просто. Спасибо)